# User unable to connect to Exchange 2007 with Outlook 2007 on her PC

Tags: outlook

One of the staff in our office is unable to connect to our Exchange 2007 server through Outlook 2007 on her workstation. She *can* access mail from a browser via https://exchange.example.com/owa/. When I try to log in with her account on a different PC, everything works fine. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Outlook on her PC, but it’s not working so far. When I ping from her PC to our Exchange server, I can ping it. So I can’t figure out whether it’s a network cable issue or an Outlook issue. But her account seems fine, as I can access it from a different PC.

Comment: Based on the troubleshooting process that you have described above, you actually *have* figured out that it is *not* a network cable issue.

Answer (score 3):

It could be her local mail profile is corrupt.  Delete the old ones, and create a new one.

As Miles notes, you can find that in the Control Panel under "Mail" or "Mail (32-bit)".

Comment: Note that the existing profile can be found and deleted in the "Mail" or "Mail (32-bit)" section of Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Remove the profile
2. Export the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook as a backup  4. Open Outlook and let it autoconfigure her profile.

I assume that you are pinging the server name via the host name, not IP address?

I don't know what the OS is, so I can't tell you exactly where it is, check your bindings in the network properties. Wherever you see all the connections for your OS, click Advanced>Advanced Settings and move the LAN connection to the top.

I used to have the same problem whenever I had a VPN open, since the binding was at the top, and it screwed up the DNS search order. Speaking of that, make sure that you check the order of your DNS servers with an IPCONFIG. If you are not using IPv6, I would also uncheck in in the network properties.